# CSS minifier choice

Tags: php, css, minify

I'm looking into upgrading to a newer CSS minifier which can minify CSS in PHP. I'm currently using an older version of https://github.com/mrclay/minify

However, I've also found http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/ which seems to update a little more frequently and is mentioned often.

What are your experiences with both libraries when it comes to speed and compatibility also with newer CSS3 rules and htc files?

I've already found that Minify has to be edited in my situation to work in my websites as the including doesn't seem to work very well when placed in another directory, which makes easy updates by replacing files more work.

The minified CSS will be stored in a CSS file once until the original CSS file is updated, so the minifier will not run too often. However, I don't want visitors to have to wait too long when they are the first to visit a site after the CSS has been updated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your CSS files is likely smaller than the average image you serve-up, so why bother?

Comment: Take into consideration that in many situations using Gzip compression on the web server often shows little or any speed increase with minified CSS.

Comment: A minified stylesheet is smaller than a non-minified one, and though the improvement is not as great as when you minify JS, it is an improvement nonetheless. Yahoo! recommends minifying CSS. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#minify

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I've already decided to use a minifier. The question just is: which one. :)

Answer (score 6):

I also normally use my own minifier:

```
<?php
function compress ($code) {
    $code = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $code);
    $code = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $code);
    $code = str_replace('{ ', '{', $code);
    $code = str_replace(' }', '}', $code);
    $code = str_replace('; ', ';', $code);

    return $code;
}
```

But have switched to SASS recently so now I use its --style=compressed.

I've also tried CSSTidy which does more than just minify and works fine with PHP:

```
<?php
include DOCROOT . 'Lib/CSSTidy/class.csstidy.php';

$cssTidy = new csstidy();

$cssTidy->parse($CSSCode);
$cssTidy->set_cfg('remove_last_;', true);

echo $cssTidy->print->plain();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using LESS. CSSTidy does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[YUI compressor](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/). You can even create an ANT task to run it over your CSSs while generating deployable version and stuff

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer doing the minification on the server.

Comment: You mean, minify every time you serve?

Comment: Every time a change is made in the CSS. After that the minified file is stored on the server.

Comment: Well, indeed. What I do for that is to use the ANT task I created to minify and copy to wherever I need it. If I test in a Tomcat container, then it copies the minified there while keeping the neat and formatted in the project.

Comment: My preferred way is to just visit the site, have the script on the server detect whether or not the CSS file(s) contain changes, and only create a new minified version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a programming question, I actually use my own, very simple minifier:

```
public static function CompressCssFile($file) {
    ob_start(array(self::GetInstance(), 'compressCss'));

    header('Cache-Control: max-age='.(3600 * 24).', must-revalidate');
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + (3600 * 168)) . ' GMT');
    header('Last modified: ' . (file_exists($file) ? filemtime($file) : gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())) . ' GMT');

    include_once $file;
    ob_end_flush();
}

private function compressCss($buffer) {
    // Remove comments:
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    // Remove tabs, excessive spaces and newlines
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '   '), '', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}
```

Works great for me.

Comment: Thanks! Do you serve the file like this, or store the minified files on the server?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

I use this on all my projects. It's easy to setup: just drop the "min" directory in your root folder, then go to http://yourserver.com/min to add files to the minify URL.

It's main advantage is for production however, it can be frustrating to use in development as the files get cached (so if your CSS file is constantly changing this isn't your best choice). However it's very powerful for combining multiple CSS or multiple JS files and caching the combined, minified file for significantly optimized load time.

---

P.S.

I use this in combination with lessphp https://github.com/leafo/lessphp 
This less PHP implementation still has some bugs regarding parsing percentages but other than that works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty good: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp
You can use it in your PHP scripts as a class or execute it from the command line. It compiles Less into CSS and can also minify it. Even if you're not using Less, it can still minify plain old CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of https://packagist.org/packages/tubalmartin/cssmin may I suggest you to give it a try? It's a PHP port initially based on YUI compressor. It should cover CSS3 just fine if you ask me ;)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://datayze.com/howto/minify-css-with-php.php) also has a nice bit of sample code with an explanation. I find this block of code to be more complete and easier to read than some of the others here:

```
function minimizeCSS($css){
    $css = preg_replace('/\/\*((?!\*\/).)*\*\//', '', $css); // negative look ahead to remove comments
    $css = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $css); // remove extra whitespace
    $css = preg_replace('/\s*([:;{}])\s*/', '$1', $css); // remove unneeded whitespace
    $css = preg_replace('/;}/', '}', $css); // remove last semicolon
    return $css;
}
```

A test is:

```
/* crazy ** /** test */ body { /* who would write css 
 like this? */background:    white   !important;}
a
{
color :blue
;
}
```

Which becomes:

```
body{background:white !important}a{color:blue}
```

Which test for correct handling of the following cases:

1. Two comments on a single line
2. Extra asterisks and slashes in a comment
3. A necessary white space that shouldn't be removed
4. A comment that spans multiple lines